# Team Foundation Corrupt in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I try open my VS Solutions I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

When I click ok:

[image: 2nd Error]

I see this error in the log file:

`C:\Users\Dylan\Dropbox\Work\Code\FSK Logging Server\FSK Logging Server\FSK_LoggingClient\FSK_LoggingClient.csproj : error  : Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed to load.`

Does any one have any Ideas? I haven't been able to work all day. I have followed other advice on other forums etc. And I have not come right.

This happened after installing VS update 3 ?

Is there a way I can Unbind my projects from TFS so that I can at least work on them?

Comment: dll should exist in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies. did the update 3 install report any issues?

Comment: Didn't report any issues. Where Can I get a copy of that dll to replace mine with?

Comment: open the sln file with a text editor there is a GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) delete it then your project should be unbound from TFS but make a copy of it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Visual Studio installer, and choose repair.  If that doesn't work, uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps someone in the future:

This worked for me:

to solve this issue delete all the files under `C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache`   and restart my VS2010 and everything gone as i need!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36f1d2e5-af78-4c8c-879e-a85dc2d6ef92/package-load-failure-microsoftvisualstudioteamfoundationversioncontrolhatpackage?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: No joy for me doing this with VS2013.  Not clearing the 3.0 nor the 5.0 cache folder.  Not even both.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I've been fighting with this issue for days and nothing worked - deleting the cache files under the \4.0\ version fixed my Team Explorer in VS 2012

Comment: This is the best answer, no reinstall, worked for me on VS2015

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue after I re-installed the Team Explorer for VS 2013. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776